# How do I action a method and pass key of dict with tkinter Scale widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, widget, ttk, tkinter-scale

I've searched for solutions to this and have tried to implement them, but am not having any success getting a tkinter `Scale` widget to call a method by setting the `command` keyword argument.

I am storing the widget objects in lists in a dictionary. The method is called when creating the lists and does indeed contain the correct objects. I'm thinking scope might be the issue here.

```
import Tkinter as Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
import ttk as ttk

class App:

    prefs = {
        "Fred": "Dead", "Kims": "Limbs"
    }

    def __init__(self, root):
        self.root = root
        self.testiter=-1
        lControls = {}
        r=0  ;  p=-1  ;  self.pSlider = 0  ;  self.pLabel = 0
        for key, var in App.prefs.items():
            lControls[key] = [] #add empty list for this key 
            p+=1
            self.pSlider=p
            s=Scale(root, from_=1, to=16, orient="horizontal",\
                    command= lambda x:self.UpdateValues(key))    #trying with 1 or no arguments
            #s=Scale(root, from_=1, to=16, orient="horizontal",\
            #        command=self.UpdateValues(key))
            #s=Scale(root, from_=1, to=16, orient="horizontal",\
            #        command=self.UpdateValues())
            #s=Scale(root, from_=1, to=16, orient="horizontal",\
            #        command=self.UpdateValues)   # <<< gives error "TypeError: UpdateValues() takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)"
            #                                         
            lControls[key].append(s)
            s.grid(row=r,column=0)

            p+=1
            self.pLabel=p
            l=Label(root, text="AAArrrgggghhhH!")
            lControls[key].append(l)
            l.grid(row=r, column=1)
            r+=1


    def UpdateValues(self, key):  #trying this with just self too
        self.testiter+=1
        print(self.testiter)


root = Tk()
App(root) 
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `UpdateValues` is called, the lambda expression uses the value of `key` as it last existed. In particular, no matter which slider you click, `key` will be whatever value was iterated through last in your loop (probably "Kims").

The typical solution for this is to put a default argument on your lambda, so that the value binds early and does not change in the next iteration of the loop.

```
s=Scale(root, from_=1, to=16, orient="horizontal",\
        command= lambda x, key=key:self.UpdateValues(key))
```

You can confirm that this works by changing the body of `UpdateValues`:

```
def UpdateValues(self, key):
    print(key)
```

When you click the top slider, it prints "Kims", and when you click the bottom slider, it prints "Fred". (Or vice-versa, since the order of iteration of a dict is implementation-dependent)